# Pages load extremely slow

Tags: javascript, html, sql, performance, loading

A friend of mine has paid for the following [webshop](http://mobielfabriq.nl/home) and has a problem. The pages load extremely slow and I can't figure out what it is. I haven't built it but the builder claims this is due to the server, which I think is a lie.  When I have a look at it in Chrome Developer Tools I can see that sometimes it is pending for more than 3 seconds. Is there a way to quickly pin-point (approximately) what the issue is?

Comment: it loads quite fast for me

Comment: In the developer tools you should be able to see what script is holding up the loading, if its actually the page that is pending for a long time then you should check to see what is running on that page

Comment: having said that, it loads fast for me

Comment: loads fast... see no problem.

Comment: Me too, i have a rather slow connection and it loads quite faster than Facebook :D

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I forget to mention the pages that load slow, for instance the page - 'alle telefoons' - 'samsung', or any other product page.

Comment: @user3301913 Its still normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is many reason causing this problem.

Might be;

- Caching problem,
- Server response time,
- Script load time,
- Big sized images

and more...

Firstly, you have to watch your site for what causing this. You can do it with a tool like;
http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

I suggest you;

- Try DB Caching technologies (search redis, mongodb)
- Try HTTP Caching technologies (search varnish)
- Avoid using uncropped images bigger than 500k
- Combine multiple js files into one file
- Combine multiple css files into one file

Explanation:

DB Caching: Database caching is the most popular technology that helps to speed up your site with caching old query results and show them to visitors without visiting the database again.

HTTP Caching: Varnish is a powerfull helper to avoid re-load every entity on your page. Varnish does not make a response to HTTP Server for load an image or another else. So without a new request, your http server flies.

Big sized images: The bigger they are, the harder they load. Try to crop your images as same size as the area that will use the image. Don't forget to compress your images with a compress tool like jpegoptimizer.

Combining asset files: When you want to load a new script or new image, every entity makes a request to http server and many request = high load time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions and explanation! I am going to forward them to him.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the major issue is some images are way bigger than they need to be.  Ideally all images should be set to their display size, rather than getting the browser to do all the work (after downloading more than is required).  I'd start by re-sizing all the images and see how you go.

Comment: Thank you, I will forward your advise!

Answer (score 0):

## See [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/b9ZBp2/http://mobielfabriq.nl/home) report here.

- You should to enable caching
- use gzip compression
- minimize redirects
- Compress images (images are taking 62.91% time to load)